# Make sure that a PutBucketWebsite operation launched via an aws cli script is executed only once the target bucket has been created

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am trying to setup an AWS S3 bucket for static website hosting.

I want to automate the operations via a script that calls **aws cli** commands.

So far my script, simplified, looks like this

```
aws s3api delete-bucket --bucket my-bucket --region eu-west-1
aws s3api create-bucket --bucket my-bucket --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=eu-west-1
aws s3 website s3://my-bucket/ --index-document index.html --error-document error.html
aws s3api put-bucket-policy --bucket my-bucket --policy file://policy.json
```

Sometimes this script works just fine. Sometimes though the following error occurs

```
An error occurred (NoSuchBucket) when calling the PutBucketWebsite operation: The specified bucket does not exist
```

I guess this has to do with the fact that I start deleting the bucket and then I build it again and when the `PutBucketWebsite operation` starts executing the bucket has not yet been recreated.

Is there a way to make sure the `PutBucketWebsite operation` is executed only once `my-bucket` has been created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the wait command to ensure the bucket exists before you try uploading to the bucket:

```
aws s3api wait bucket-exists --bucket my-bucket
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/wait/bucket-exists.html

This will poll every 5 seconds until the bucket is created.

It might also be a good idea to confirm that the bucket has been deleted properly before trying to recreate it:

```
aws s3api wait bucket-not-exists --bucket my-bucket
```